# Typescript: Is there a way to say that class implements its generic type?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an `AbstractPageComponent` class that has a `setData` method:

```js
abstract class AbstractPageComponent<TPageData extends object> {
  setData(data: TPageData) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}
```

So the question is how to tell Typescript that `AbstractPageComponent` class implements `TPageData`? This doesn't work:

```js
abstract class AbstractPageComponent<TPageData extends object> implements TPageData {...}
```

Currently using this abstract class is not very convenient:

```js
interface SomePageData {
  foo: FooItem;
  bar: BarItem;
}

export class SomePageComponent 
  extends AbstractPageComponent<SomePageData>
  implements SomePageData {
  foo: FooItem;
  bar: BarItem;
}
```

It requires end-user to write `implements SomePageData` and duplicate all its fields. What I want to achieve is this:

```js
interface SomePageData {
  foo: FooItem;
  bar: BarItem;
}

export class SomePageComponent 
  extends AbstractPageComponent<SomePageData> {
  someMethod() {
    // this.foo and this.bar are available
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Typescript treats class type quite differently from other type that's created using `type` or `interface` keyword.

The code you're currently using is pretty much the optimal solution IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

Would you please try the following:

```
export class AbstractPageComponent<T> implements T {
}
```

And in another file:

```
interface SomePageData{
   foo: FooItem;
   bar: BarItem;
}

export class SomePageComponent extends AbstractPageComponent<SomePageData> {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the original question I mentioned that this doesn't work: `TS2422: A class may only implement another class or interface`.